# Why Unit failed,docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly?

Tags: docker

My logs

```
The unit docker.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
мар 05 09:29:56 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
мар 05 09:29:56 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
мар 05 09:29:56 miki-IdeaPad systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd



systemctl status docker.service
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-03-05 09:29:56 WET; 5min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.
docker info

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    25.0.3
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.12.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.24.5
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

I read many posts on Docker forums,but no help.

```
3922 srw-rw----  1 root              docker     0 мар  5 09:29 docker.sock
```

What should I try?